# Arguments for imshow in matplotlib are ambiguous

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand what the order for correct dimensions for `imshow` should be. [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) appears conflicting.

Is it (n,m) or MXN? 
Is it (m,n) or NXM?

Or is there a difference?

It looks like they are swapping stuff around randomly.

Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: The fact that they have used different letters, or capitalised version of the same letters, is misleading. The documentation here is just saying that imshow takes different shaped arrays which are interpreted and plotted differently

Comment: The order is also reversed

Comment: I opened [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10323) about it.

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a bit confusing. What is meant here is of course that an array of `M x N` elements has shape `(n,m)`, where `N=n` and `M=m`. This however deviates from the usual convention of defining matrix dimensions.

The usual convention for matrices is "N by M" meaning a matrix of `N` rows and `M` columns; this would have "shape `(N,M)`" (in the numpy convention).

For some reason the imshow documentation deviates from that convention. I guess one could change that.

Concerning the possible dimensions for `imshow` the correct version should read

> `X` : array_like, shape `(n, m)` or `(n, m, 3)` or `(n, m, 4)`
>
> Display the image in X to current axes. X may be an array or a PIL image. If X is an array, it can have the following shapes and types:
>
> `n x m` / `(n,m)` – values to be mapped (float or int)
>   `n x m x 3` / `(n,m,3)` – RGB (float or uint8)
>   `n x m x 4` / `(n,m,4)` – RGBA (float or uint8)
>
> The value for each component of `n x m x 4` and `n x m x 4` float arrays should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0. `n x m` arrays are mapped to colors based on the norm (mapping scalar to scalar) and the cmap (mapping the normed scalar to a color).

Here `n` is the number of rows, `m` is the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the array you pass to the function imshow() is (n,m). That means you have an array with n rows and m columns.
There is no flipping of the array, as one could assume from the documentation.